# Nested aggregate pipeline for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection with lots of documents in the follow format:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "581f9eae05711c35f461d779"
    },
    "eventID": "Illinois84bc00edc91c24a95573",
    "type": "voteup",
    "update": "f3a44be56669e01cf02ed685c97451ba",
    "count": 1,
}
```

I need to be able to run an aggregate from my server on the collection and return a JSON object which:

Groups the data by eventID (there are many eventIDs), then groups the documents in those groups by update (there are many updates, each associated to an eventID), then for each eventID/Update group, sums the 'count' values of each of the documents which are of type "voteup" and "votedown".

So an actual output might look like:

```
{
    "events": [
    //  array of objects, one for each unique eventID
        {
            "eventID": "Idaho4532543trt3424f",
            "updates": [
            //  array of objects, one for each unique update
                {
                    "update": "rh43782ty738tywuioty34",
                    "voteup": 12,  // the number of documents with that eventID/update which are type "voteup"
                    "votedown": 1  // the number of documents with that eventID/update which are type "voteudown"
                },
                {
                    "update": "hfu89h834hw8uoglthyw78",
                    "voteup": 2,
                    "votedown": 32
                },
                {
                    "update": "as09g8fgdsiuhgofhdosug",
                    "voteup": 123,
                    "votedown": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        //  here's another event...
        {
            "eventID": "Texas38tr943uytwo9grs",
            "updates": [
                {
                    "update": "2ty738tywuioty34rh4378",
                    "voteup": 0,
                    "votedown": 1
                },
                {
                    "update": "34hw8uoglthyw78hfu89hv",
                    "voteup": 22,
                    "votedown": 72
                },
                {
                    "update": "dsiuhgofhdosugas09g8fg",
                    "voteup": 67,
                    "votedown": 11
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The following does the job of counting how many eventID/update/type documents are:

```
{
    $group: {

        _id: { eventID: "$eventName", updateID: "$update", sentiment: "$type" }

    }
},
```

But the output is simply a flat array of each. Is there a way to have aggregate produce a nested object like the one above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you could group on `eventID` and `update`, and then group on `eventID`, while doing `$push` the `update` into an array

```
{$group: {
    _id: {eventID: '$eventID', update: '$update'},
    voteup: {$sum: {$cond: [
            {$eq: ['$type', {$literal: 'voteup'}]},
            1,
            0
        ]}},
    votedown: {$sum: {$cond: [
            {$eq: ['$type', {$literal: 'voteup'}]},
            0,
            1
        ]}}
}},

{$group: {
    _id: {eventID: '$_id.eventID'},
    updates: {$push: {
        update: '$_id.update',
        voteup: '$voteup',
        votedown: '$votedown'
    }}
}}
```

Comment: One tiny error in there; in the second $group the $id.eventID needs to be $_id.eventID.

Comment: ...but your solution is *exactly* what I was after. Thank you!